Find regex to get numbers surrounded by space
Hello i want to have regex that takes first occurring digits if it have space before and after
For example :
"Do work 1234 hard, some city, MN 55123" -> it should give result as " 1234 " (with before and after space)

"DDrt fgyu MN
1155 East sdd Road
fff, IL 60563" -> no match as 1155 does not have space before.

"yyy 33 go 45678 util" -> it should give result as " 33 " (with before and after space)

"55 sadf sadf." -> no match

"PO BOX 12" -> no match

i tried different regex like
(?s).*?(\d+).*
(?s).*?(\s\d+\s).*
(?s)(?<=\w)(\s\d+\s)(?=\w.*) and others but none worked.


Note that the character class \s (whitespace) also contains \n etc. If you want to have numbers surrounded by space (blank) characters only, then you could use ( \d+ ) for the group. Btw, since you seem to want to extract the capturing group you're probably using Pattern and Matcher in which case you don't need the .* surrounding the group. Just use Matcher#find() mutliple times until it returns false.

Btw, why should "yyy 33 go 45678 util" only yield" 33 " and not " 45678 " as well? You could, of course get this by just calling Matcher#find() only once to get the first result, but is that what you want?

@Thomas i am using String's replaceAll like one.replaceAll(regex, "$1");

Just to clarify because you didn't answer this yet: do you just one to replace the first number that's surrounded by space, i.e. any other such numbers in a string should be ignored?

You should not replace when you need to extract. And the right regex is (?<!\S)\d+(?!\S), it will handle overlapping matches as well since the lookarounds do not consume characters.

@Thomas yes if String s = "yyy 33 go 45678 util" then s = s.replaceAll(regex,$1) should have value as " 33 ".

In that case you're probably missing a "reluctant" quantifier, i.e. make .* match as little as possible. Try replaceAll("?s).*?( \\d+ ).*", "$1") - the main change would be .*? which is a reluctant version of .*. That means the group will match the first occurence of such a number rather than the last.

if you want to find one space ,digits, and one space, what is wrong with " \\d+ " ?   e.g. https://ideone.com/H4JAXi

Here is the regex you need. A space followed by one or more digits followed by another space.
" \d+ "

Here is this expression working on your test strings: s1 s2 s3 s4 s5
